# Como faço para liberar meu botão ' + ' , apenas quando seleciono um item da lista?

Tags: javascript, angular

Estou com um problema no `ngFor`, pois quero habilitar o botão + somente quando um item da lista for selecionado. Mas meu elemento `option` não aceita o event bind `(click)`. Podem me ajudar?

`<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <button (click)="setItem()">Items</button>
    <select class="custom-select">
      <option *ngFor="let item of itemSelecionado">{{ item }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" [disabled]="isActive">+</button>
</div>`

```
itemSelecionado = [];
items = ['Teste A', 'Teste B', 'Teste C', 'Teste D', 'Teste E'];
isActive = true;

setItem(){
  this.itemSelecionado = this.items;
  console.log(this.itemSelecionado);
}
```

Eu já tentei criar o método abaixo e usá-lo no `option`, mas não deu certo:

`liberaBtn() {
    this.isActive = false;
  }`

Comment: O que esse botão ira fazer? Adicionar mais campos ?

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés do click use:

```
 <select class="custom-select" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let item of itemSelecionado">{{ item }}</option>
    </select>
```

no ts coloque:

```
onChange(){

}
```